# Do we want the site statistics on the home page back?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Until the day we graduated (16 December) we had a small table with site statistics on the home page. This has always been a feature specific to beta sites, so it was removed after we graduated. In my last screenshot of the site statistics, the data looked as follows:

| Site Stats |  |
| --- | --- |
| questions | 1,229 |
| answers | 1,931 |
| answered | 82% |
| users | 7,333 |
| visitors/day | 515 |

(Apparently, it is not possible to create a table without a header row, hence "Site Stats" in the first row.)

The [Area51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) provided some more data, such as questions per day and the answers per questions ratio, but those data are now frozen.

Even though our site has graduated, I would still like to have some data to help track the "health" of our site. Bringing back the home page statistics would allow that. It would not require the introduction of a new feature; restoring what was there for more than four years would be sufficient.

What do other people think about bringing back the home page site statistics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think bringing back this table would be helpful to having a good understanding of site activity.